# DIV Preloader with jQuery

Tags: jquery, preload

I have a Javascript code for div preloading, but i need preloadin with jQuery.
this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById('preload').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ajax-loader').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
div#preload{
        display:none;
        margin:0 auto;
  }
</style>

<img src="/images/ajax.gif" id="ajax-loader"  />
<div id="preload">Some text</div>
```

How i can make a preload with fadeout for a DIV with jquery?
thank u

Comment: Why do you need jQuery when you have it working in javascript? Are you looking for some effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the exact equivalent to the javascript but it looks like it will do what you want:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/84j5S/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#preload').show();
   $('#ajax-loader').hide();
});
```

The equivalent is:

Working Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/84j5S/2/

```
$(document).ready(functon() {
   $('#preload').css('display','block');
   $('#ajax-loader').css('display','none');
});
```

These jquery solutions are the same as doing this via css:

```
#preload {display:block}
#ajax-loader {display:none}
```

Although unless you are going to be adding jquery to your project there is no reason to include the library just to do this.

Comment: `$('#ajax-loader').fadeOut()`

Comment: Check out all the default effects:  http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/  Also, please mark the answer if it helped you by clicking the checkmark so that future users will be helped.

Comment: You need to include jquery on your page before you run that code.

Comment: i know it, but after i add this code in Dreamweaver i got syntax error:  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(functon() {
   $('#preload').show();
   $('#ajax-loader').hide();
});
</script>

Comment: There was a typo in my answer.. it should be `function`.. I had originally written `funcion`

Comment: @Alireza I've included 2 working demos.. if the code doesn't run for you it means you have other issues on your page.

Comment: i dont wanna see "SOME TEXT" befor and after loading gif!

Comment: Please chek my first code, i need something like that with jquery

Comment: I've already provide you all the examples.  It is very simple to make it fadeout:  `$('#preload').fadeOut();`